# How to implement a C# interface in F#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, f#

I would like to implement the following C# interface in F#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Mono.Addins;

[TypeExtensionPoint]
public interface ISparqlCommand
{
    string Name { get; }
    object Run(Dictionary<string, string> NamespacesDictionary,    org.openrdf.repository.Repository repository, params object[] argsRest);
}
```

This is what I have tried, but it gives me: "Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression"

```
#light

module Module1

open System
open System.Collections.Generic;

type MyClass() =
    interface ISparqlCommand with
        member this.Name = 
            "Finding the path between two tops in the Graph"
        member this.Run(NamespacesDictionary, repository, argsRest) = 
            new System.Object
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe indentation is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps just missing the parens on `new System.Object()`?

Comment: What's a C# interface? You've defined a CLR interface in C#.

Answer (score 5):

I verified @Mark's answer in the comments.  Given the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace org.openrdf.repository {
    public class Repository {
    }
}

namespace CSLib
{

    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Interface)]
    public class TypeExtensionPoint : System.Attribute
    {
        public TypeExtensionPoint()
        {
        }
    }


    [TypeExtensionPoint]
    public interface ISparqlCommand
    {
        string Name { get; }
        object Run(Dictionary<string, string> NamespacesDictionary, org.openrdf.repository.Repository repository, params object[] argsRest);
    }

}
```

The following F# implementation (only change is adding `()` at the object construction) works "fine":

```
#light

module Module1

open System
open System.Collections.Generic;
open CSLib

type MyClass() =
    interface ISparqlCommand with
        member this.Name = 
            "Finding the path between two tops in the Graph"
        member this.Run(NamespacesDictionary, repository, argsRest) = 
            new System.Object()
```

Though you don't need to use `#light` anymore (it is the default) and you may want to head the `NamespaceDictionary` paramater name warning that "Uppercase variable identifiers should not generally be used in patterns, and may indicate a misspelt pattern name." Also note that you will need to cast `MyClass` to `ISparqlCommand` in order to access the implemented members (not a question you asked, but easy to get confused by coming from C#): e.g `(MyClass() :> ISparqlCommand).Name`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone! The following code actually works:

```
namespace MyNamespace

open System
open System.Collections.Generic;
open Mono.Addins

[<assembly:Addin>]
    do()
[<assembly:AddinDependency("TextEditor", "1.0")>]
    do()

[<Extension>]
type MyClass() =
    interface ISparqlCommand with
         member this.Name
             with get() = 
                 "Finding the path between two tops in a Graph"
         member this.Run(NamespacesDictionary, repository, argsRest) = 
             new System.Object()
```

It is also an example of how to use Mono.Addins with F#